# How to kill all jobs running in background (unix) which ran with script in screen?

Tags: bash, kill, gnu-screen

I ran 1000 background jobs with bash script in screen mode.
How can I kill all those jobs at a same time.

How I ran all jobs:

```
screen
#enter
bash script.sh

## script.sh:
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..1000}
   do
      program -k $i -o out$i &
   done
```

Comment: I think `pkill program` would suffice

Answer (score 0):

To kill all instances of `bash script.sh` use

`kill $(ps aux | grep 'bash script.sh' | awk '{print $2}')`

Using pkill will not work since the script has been invoked as `bash script.sh` .

Comment: `pkill -f script.sh` would kill anything with `script.sh` in the command line which might be good enough, or `pkill -f 'bash script.sh'` will do too